# Cannot update table , when comparing data between two cursors

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I wanted to compare rows of a table to find out if they are equal or not ,
what i did was create 2 cursors 
1. Select links from table where visted = yes
2. Select links from table where visted = No
Using for loop and if statement i want to compare visited links with not visited links if they are equal or not and if they are equal then update visted of that link to "YES" 
Not done yet (My aim was to exit the program if all links are visted and all marked YES or the cursor for " where visited=no " returns a null value)
My portion code:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
import HTMLParser
from HTMLParser import HTMLParseError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='shailang',
    db='mydb')
    cursor = mydb.cursor()

    def process2(url):
       flag=0
       cursor.execute("SELECT links FROM DATA_urls where visited = 'Ye'")
       Yes_rows = cursor.fetchall()
       cursor.execute("SELECT links FROM DATA_urls where visited = 'No'")
       No_rows = cursor.fetchall()
       for No_links in No_rows: 
        print 'NOOOOOOOOOO'
        k= No_links
        print k
        for Yes_links in Yes_rows:
            print "YESSSSSSSSSSSSSS"
                k1 = Yes_links
            print k1



            if k1 == k :
                print 'EQUALS'
                cursor.execute("UPDATE DATA_urls SET visited = 'Ye' where links = %s",k)
            mydb.commit()
def process(url):
    proxies = {"http":"http://proxy4.nehu.ac.in:3128",
        "https":"https://proxy4.nehu.ac.in:3128"}
    page = urllib.urlopen(url,proxies=None)
    text = page.read()
    page.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    file=open('s.txt','w') 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATA_urls(links,parent,visited) VALUES(%s,'NULL','Ye')",url)
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        print tag['href']
        if re.match(ur'(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?\xab\xbb\u201c\u201d\u2018\u2019]))',tag['href']):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DATA_urls(links,parent,visited) VALUES(%s,%s,'No')", (tag['href'],url))
        file.write('\n')
        file.write(tag['href'])
            #file.close()
   # cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM url")
   # rows = cursor.fetchall()
    mydb.commit()
    process2(1) 


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print 'No url !!'      
        sys.exit(1)
    for url in sys.argv[1:]:
        process(url)

main()
```

I got no error , but nothing is updated in my database
My table DESC:

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| links   | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| parent  | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| visited | varchar(2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to 
     mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
      user='root',
      passwd='shailang',
      db='mydb')
      cursor = mydb.cursor()

```
  def process2(url):
  flag=0
  cursor.execute("SELECT links FROM DATA_urls where visited = Ye")
 Yes_rows = cursor.fetchall()
 cursor.execute("SELECT links FROM DATA_urls where visited = No")
 No_rows = cursor.fetchall()
 count = len(No_rows)
 for i in range(0, count):
  print 'NOOOOOOOOOO'
  k= No_links
  print k
  for j in range (i+1, count):
    print "YESSSSSSSSSSSSSS"
        k1 = Yes_links
    print k1
    if k1 == k :
        print 'EQUALS'
        cursor.execute("UPDATE DATA_urls SET visited =
    'Ye' where links = %s",k)
```

[help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659513/how-to-compare-the-rows-of-a-table-using-python)

Comment: But count is for len(No_rows), how is it possible for Yes_links as well

Comment: i Dont understand the changes u made @sirmagid can u help explaining it to me ..i am new to Python

Comment: send  link download ,db and full source .py